# HTTParty doesn't print response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

What am I doing wrong? I'm connecting to an external API:

```
class Shipup
  include HTTParty
  base_uri ENV['SHIPUP_URL']

  def initialize
    @options = { }
  end

  def sendTracker(tracker)
    self.class.post("/trackers", @options.merge!({
      body: {
        trackers: [tracker]
      }
    }))
  end
end

puts Shipup.new().sendTracker({...})
```

it doesn't print out anything either if it succeeds or fails.

Comment: Is your *base_uri* valid ?

Comment: Yes, it works !

Comment: Maybe this is a long shot... but try
`shipup = Shipup.new()`

`pp shipup.sendTracker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it parsed the body which is an empty string in this case. If you need other response information, it is accessible like so:

```
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```